# How to move all directories containing e.g. mp3 into another directory?

Tags: find, mp3, directory-structure

I have plenty of directories containing MP3 files on my computer (Ubuntu 22.04), e.g. in my `/home` , `/data` , on some partitions, etc. I would like to regroup/consolidate them by moving all these directories (most directories being name with the name of the music album...) into one MP3 directory.

I know who to look to `.mp3` files (`find -iname '*.mp3'`) and I know how to move the files found by `find` (`-exec mv`). However, I don't know how to move the directory containing the data found.

Any idea?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following bash pipeline:

```bash
find /path/to/src -iname '*.mp3' -type f -printf '%h\0' |
    perl -0e 'print sort{length($b)<=>length($a)}keys%{{map {$_,1}<>}}' |
    xargs -0 echo mv --backup=t -t /path/to/dst
```

It does the following:

- `\0` and `-0` will use null separators instead of newlines, to handle strange directory names.
- `find /path/to/src` lists everything under `src`

  - `-iname '*.mp3'` filters for the `.mp3` extension
  - `-type f` excludes folders somehow with that extension
  - `-printf '%h\0'` gets the directories the files are contained in
- `perl -0e 'print ...'` runs a script:

  - [`sort{length($b)<=>length($a)}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40786477/10477326) avoids errors by moving longer paths to the top so subdirectories are moved before their parents
  - `keys%{{map {$_,1}<>}}` removes duplicates i.e. when one directory has two or more `.mp3` files
- `xargs` takes each input line i.e. directory and gives it to a command as parameters

  - `echo` you should remove after you check this is doing what you want
  - `mv -t /path/to/dst` moves the file to the destination. `-t` lets us specify the destination directory before the source filesystem path to let `xargs` put the path at the end.

    - `--backup=t` numbers the directories when there are two with same name in different places

This moves subdirectories out first even when a parent contains a `.mp3`. If you (like @PeterCordes) want to change this behavior, simply swap `$a` and `$b` in the perl script. This would reverse the sort so that parent directories are moved first. The remaining errors about the no-longer-existing parents can be ignored or silenced with a final `2>/dev/null`. Thank you @Raffa for many included improvements.

#### Example setup

```
./src
./src/a
./src/a/a
./src/a/a/a
./src/a/a/a/a.mp3
./src/a/a.mp3
./src/d
./src/d/other.txt
./src/helloworld
./src/helloworld/c.mp3
./dst
```

#### Example result

```
./src
./src/d
./src/d/other.txt
./dst
./dst/a
./dst/a/a
./dst/a/a.mp3
./dst/a.~1~
./dst/a.~1~/a.mp3
./dst/helloworld
./dst/helloworld/c.mp3
```

Comment: If `foo/bar/x.mp3` and `foo/y.mp3` both exist, this will `mv -t dst  foo/bar` then `mv -t dst  foo`, rather than just moving the whole `foo`?  So this will at least affect timestamps on directories within subtrees.  IDK if there are other possible effects, like `mv` prompting about `dst/foo` already existing.

Comment: @PeterCordes The question asked to move all the directories, and didn't say to excluding subdirectories when the parent is to be moved. But it's easy to adapt this to work the way you describe. Simply swap `$a` and `$b` to reverse the sort in the perl print sort line step. Then parent directories are moved first, and you can just ignore the errors about the child directories no longer existing after the parent is moved

Comment: If you add the `-depth` option maybe you *can* use uniq (or `uniq -z` in the version that uses `-printf '%h\0'`) - and don't need the perl sort at all?

Comment: The `-depth` doesn't work. I have `a/b/c/{hi.mp3,f/hi.mp3}` and it returned `a/b/c` before `a/b/c/f`.. What I was able to do was merge the `sort`/`uniq` into the perl script